# Objective-c: sort NSMutableArray by OBJECT_IN_ARRAY.NSNUMBER

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray

OK, this is my problem:

I have a `NSMutableArray` (`hsdbarray`) with objects (`highscoresdbObj`) in it.

I want to sort the objects in the array by `OBJECT.NSNumber` (`highscoresdbObj.hsdbname`) descending.

Could someone please help me?

Sincerly Jonny! :)

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but consider using readable names. To my tired eyes after hours of reading, "highscoresdbObj.hsdbname" is about as meaningful as alphabet soup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSortDescriptor) with the key "hsdbname" and descending order. Tell the [array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to sort using this descriptor.